# How to grab data inside a link that has event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to grab some data from a like that has event like this:

```
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'View Seller Contact', 'Alfa Romeo', '147');" style="min-width: 123px;" data-id="161795" data-click="view-seller-contact" class="btn btn-primary-blue btn-xs " href="#">View Seller Contact</a>
```

This link will show data after click on it. I want to grab the data that show after the link was click. I wonder how can I grab data from this kind of things? Pls anyone give me any idea.Pls guide me. Thanks in advace

Comment: please give example for `want to grab the data that show after the link was click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the `data-` attributes values of the link (`data-id="161795"` and `data-click="view-seller-contact"` in your example), use the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) method.

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    var linkData = $(this).data();
});
```

The `linkData` variable will be an object - `{ id: 161795, click: "view-seller-contact" }`. Use it how you want )

Comment: How can I get data from { id: 161795, click: "view-seller-contact" }? Pls guide me

Comment: @DooDoo, well, it's a regular Javascript object. You can access its properties by `linkData.click` or `linkData['click']`. More on this here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1):

you mean the attributes of the anchor tag when it is clicked?

first pass the reference of current element as `this` to the `ga` method

```
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'View Seller Contact', 'Alfa Romeo', '147', this);" style="min-width: 123px;" data-id="161795" data-click="view-seller-contact" class="btn btn-primary-blue btn-xs " href="#">View Seller Contact</a>
```

now in the `ga()` method you can do

```
function ga( arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, thisObj )
{
   $(thisObj).data('id')
   //rest of the code
}
```